# Accessing VMware's Bios

Tags: vmware, virtualization, bios, vmware-fusion

On a Mac in VMware Fusion when the vm is starting and the loading bar is displayed, how can you access the the boot order as if it were a stand alone windows machine?

I've tried "f8" "delete" with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know VMware on Mac, but on Windows, I'd use in Menu VM->Power->Power on to BIOS.

While startup of the VM, BIOS setup is launched with F2, boot order menu with F12.